# Call an SQL method from a different usercontrol C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Apologies if this is obvious, this is new to me. I am running WPF and am trying to call data from an SQL database into a grid using two different UserControls.

One will contain the DataGrid where it will be displayed. The 2nd will be a control panel on the left hand side which includes a button to run the SQL query and (hopefully) populate the DataGrid in the other form.

I can call a simple method (display a message box) with this button but for some reason can't do this. How can I press that button on the 'control' UserControl to run the SQL query and make it populate on the 'main' control? Any help would be appreciated.

On the 'control' UserControl I have:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;   

namespace WpfApp2
{

public partial class PortfolioControl : UserControl
{

    public PortfolioControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
    } 

    public void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Portfolio Portfolio1 = new Portfolio(this);
        FillGridTest();
    }

public void FillGridTest()
    {
        Portfolio Portfolio1 = new Portfolio(this);

        string connectionString = "user id=username etc...";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM etc...";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "PortfolioReport");
        Portfolio1.grid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["PortfolioReport"].DefaultView;
    }
}
```

And then on the larger UserControl that has the DataGrid I have the following:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp2
{

public partial class Portfolio : UserControl
{
    public Portfolio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private PortfolioControl _PortfolioControl;
    public Portfolio(PortfolioControl masterForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _PortfolioControl = masterForm;

    }
}
```

}

The XAML on the 'main' control is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp2.Portfolio"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
   compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="706" 
 Margin="27,26,-1124,-432" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1397"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
  Margin="648,574,-468,-297" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

  </Grid>
```

Comment: What your question is?

Comment: I've updated now to hopefully be clearer

Comment: @user8970760, your question lack more code... Ok, you coded `button1_Click` but we can't devise when nor how this is called, hence, neither help you. Maybe you could upload the whole project somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I've added some more now

Comment: See my two form project.  It is a window form project, but it is the same principal on transferring data between two classes : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block.

Answer (score 0):

In this method

```
public void FillGridTest()
{
    Portfolio Portfolio1 = new Portfolio(this);
    ...
    Portfolio1.grid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["PortfolioReport"].DefaultView;
}
```

The control Portfolio was created but not shown anywhere.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about showing that on Portfolio:Usercontrol? Thanks

Comment: @user8970760 Put the control Portfolio inside PortfolioControl like this
    
 <DockPanel>
     <..../>
  <local:Portfolio x:Name="portfolio"/>
 </DockPanel>
    
Then in method FillGridTest(), assign items source: portfolio.grid1.ItemsSource=...

Comment: @user8970760 Put the control Portfolio into your PortfolioControl, or show Portfolio in a new window